# efficient and readable way to isolate group of bits

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Given offset OFF and length LEN, isolate a group of bits and shift it to the right. (Usage: int holding several smaller-range integers with given offsets and lengths). For example using offset 4 and length 4,

```
  a = 110101011000
      ----^^^^---- this is the group 
      000000000101
              ^^^^ isolated and right-shifted here
```

I currently use

```
(a>>OFF)&((1<<(LEN+1))-1)
```

giving for the example above

```
a                         110101011000
a>>OFF                    000011010101
1<<(LEN+1)                000000010000
1<<(LEN+1)-1              000000001111
(a>>OFF)&((1<<(LEN+1))-1) 000000000101
```

Is there a more readable/efficient way?

Comment: The expression is fine - just put it in a macro or inline function and forget about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a single correct answer in this case. What you did is fine - it's correct, and with some documentation it's also pretty clear.

If you want different ways, you can: try shifting `a` left and then right again (assuming `a` is unsigned - otherwise cast it first); or you can first create a mask (in your case: 000011110000), bitwise-and, and only then shift. However, these won't necessarily be prettier than what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

110101011000

Shift left
010110000000

Shift right
000000000101

This is more readable..!